# how to handle query string in site map path

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

i am having a condition in which i have to pass the query string in the URL, the page which i am calling contains the Site map path control.

But as i pass the query string with the URL, the site map path is not working.

Can anybody tell me that how can i handle query string in site mat path control as i have web.sitemap file containing the nodes

Thanks

Edited : my url is like
 http://localhost:1400/RevenueAccounting/Auth/BillingAdministration/RackHireDueDetails.aspx?t=1&LiableRoad=BNSF

having 2 varables in query string, the first variable will remain same always but the value of second variable changes

the actual error is, when i am using just the URL

http://localhost:1400/RevenueAccounting/Auth/BillingAdministration/RackHireDueDetails.aspx?t=1

in web.sitemap then the site map is not showing on page, and the value of second variable changes so how could i use site map path for this condition

Comment: Maybe you can provide a sample query string, and the actual error of what is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do it directly in the web.sitemap but you will have to do it in code-behind. 
Check if this helps: [Programmatically Modify Site-Map Nodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178425.aspx)

Comment: SiteMap.SiteMapResolve event has issue it some time fire and some time not.